# Bug when showing "Warning: This site is in Private Beta"

Tags: bug

When I try to load AI.SE without logging in, I get a

> Warning: this site is currently in **private beta** for at least 1 more day.

[image]

That **private beta** should be **private beta**, right?

Comment: Yes it should. Evidently, the text was written with the assumption it would be parsed as Markdown, but whatever displays it doesn't do that parsing. (This sort of display issue tends to creep into tag wiki excerpts too.)

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to ask this on Meta.SE instead.

Comment: @wythagoras But as far as I can tell, it only applies to AI. [i2p.SE] loaded it with the bold properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Welcome to public beta!](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/welcome-to-public-beta)

Comment: @kenorb What? This is a bug report o_o

Comment: Bug which is not relevant anymore, since we're already in public beta, so you cannot reproduce it anymore. So Public beta is the follow up post, unless you want to close it as off-topic or something.

Comment: @kenorb Close it as [status-completed]. :P